# Unable to resolve service for type 'BloodBank.DAL.ApplicationContext' while attempting to activate 'BloodBank.DAL.Repositories.DonorRepository'

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My Repository like that.

```
public class DonorRepository : BaseRepository<Donor>, IDonorRepository
    {
        public DonorRepository(ApplicationContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
        {
        }
    }


public interface IDonorRepository : IBaseRepository<Donor>
    {
    }

public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        T GetById(object EntityId);
        List<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter = null);
        void Add(T Entity);
        void Delete(T Entity);
    }

public abstract class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private  ApplicationContext _context;
        protected ApplicationContext context { get { return _context; } }
        protected BaseRepository(ApplicationContext dbContext)
        {
            _context = dbContext;
        }
        public virtual void Add(T Entity)
        {
            _context.Add<T>(Entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T Entity)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Remove(Entity);
        }

        public virtual List<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter = null)
        {
            return _context.Set<T>().ToList();
        }

        public virtual T GetById(object EntityId)
        {
            var propInfo = GetIdPropInfo();
            return _context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(x => (int)propInfo.GetValue(x) == (int)EntityId);
        }

        
        private PropertyInfo GetIdPropInfo()
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            var result = "Id";
            return type.GetProperty(result);
        }
    }
```

And my ApplicationContext

```
 public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
        {


        }
        public DbSet<Donor> Donors { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

I use repository like that:

```
public class DonorService : IDonorService
    {
        private IDonorRepository donorRepository;
        public DonorService(IDonorRepository donorRepository)
        {
            this.donorRepository = donorRepository;
        }
    }
```

And my program.cs

```
 static class Program
    {
        public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);

            ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider())
            {
                var MainForm = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainForm>();
                Application.Run(MainForm);
            }
        }
        static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<IDonorService, DonorService>();

            serviceCollection.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(DbContext), typeof(ApplicationContext));
            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(IDonorRepository), typeof(DonorRepository));

        }
    }
```

When i start this WinForm project i get this error:

"Unable to resolve service for type 'BloodBank.DAL.ApplicationContext' while attempting to activate 'BloodBank.DAL.Repositories.DonorRepository'."

What and where did I make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```cs
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(
   opt => opt.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));
```

Comment: @rusanow Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line you register your `ApplicationContext` type to be resolved whenever something requests a `DbContext`:

```cs
serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(DbContext), typeof(ApplicationContext));
```

However, your `DonorRepository` and your `BaseRepository<T>` classes don't request a `DbContext` but an `ApplicationContext`.

So you either need to register your `ApplicationContext` to be resolved for a requested `ApplicationContext`, or you need to replace all occurrences of `ApplicationContext` with `DbContext` in your `DonorRepository` and `BaseRepository<T>` classes.

---

Unrelated to the actual question, you are likely to need to use `serviceCollection.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()` and `optionsBuilder.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider).UseSqlServer()` when using a service provider with EF Core in a console project.